# Ubuntu solo install on Macbook doesn't boot anymore

Tags: boot, partitioning, macbook

I have been running Ubuntu as the sole OS on my Macbook for a while now. I don't remember the exact installation process but the important point is that I deleted the OSX partition back then and that the device would normally boot straight to the password prompt for my encrypted Ubuntu partition.

However, a few days ago the Macbook stopped booting. This happened after I left the device turned on but idling for a few hours and shut it down when I noticed I had left it running. Trying to shut it down via the GUI brought up a message about some error with my session so I typed `sudo shutdown now` in the console which turned off the computer.

Since this incident, I haven't been able to boot anymore. After turning on the Macbook, I'm stuck on a black screen without any sort of boot info coming up at any point. Booting while holding Alt shows online recovery as the only available option.

The first suggested fix I tried was to hold down Cmd, Alt, P and R during startup which apparently clears NVRAM. Now I at least get a flashing symbol of a folder with a question mark after startup, but still no option to boot.

The second thing I did was to boot to a Ubuntu live USB. From there I've been able to unlock and mount my partition and the data looks fine, but obviously that doesn't help with the booting. I also ran `fsck` on the unlocked device which didn't bring up any errors.

What else can I try to fix this? Manually backing up the data and doing a new install of Ubuntu is only my plan B, obviously.

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you using? Is it a standard Ubuntu (Unity) install?

Comment: It's Xubuntu (xfce), version 16.04.

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) from your emergency boot disk. This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: These are the results: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24224783/